# My dynamic web project doesn't show up in my GlassFish server?

Tags: java, glassfish, webserver

The Server is up and running and synchronised but my web app HelloWorld doesn't show up in Applications? 
Any Idea what's up with this?

Comment: Try to look at the server's logs .

Comment: One of the things it says is - "invalid zip file: file:/private/var/folders/pt/wkjy7wbd321_b1w4blb7ws5w0000gp/T/HelloWorld6763251211019466991.java"

Comment: Yeah I tried googling this exception and nothing showed up